# Null pointer exception in creating an array of JSONArray

Tags: java, json

I am creating a array of JSONArray objects as:

```
JSONArray Records[] = new JSONArray[10];
```

However, whenever I try to access it, I an getting a null pointer exception using the below code:

```
int sizeOfOneArr = Records[2].length();
```

Am I missing an important concept?

Comment: By default arrays are initialized with "null" content. Thus,  Records[2] is probably null. Also, variable names should be lowercase.

Comment: `new JSONArray[10]` creates array *for* objects, not array *of* objects. It is filled with default values which for references is `null` and `null` doesn't have `length()` method (nor any method/field).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new JSONArray[10];` means an Array object is created whose size is 10. Each of the 10 places still is unassigned and is *null*. You need to explicitly assign object of type JSONArray to reference at each index of array.